# Symfony Form Country City

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have symfony project. I have entity Developer and field Country and City. In FORM I want to be created -  when select the country, it appears in the city (city of this country) And if developer have ip - 
can be determined by ip. How I do this, maybe bundle or lib? Help

```
class Developer extends CustomUser
{
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255,  unique=false, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Length(min=3, max=255)
 */
protected $email;
    /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $country;
    /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="location", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $location;
```

and form

```
class DeveloperPersonalInformationType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array                $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('firstname', null, array('label' => 'First Name', 'max_length' => 255, 'required' => false))
        ->add('lastname', null, array('label' => 'Last Name', 'max_length' => 255, 'required' => false))
        ->add('email', null, array('label' => 'Email', 'max_length' => 255, 'required' => false))
        ->add('country', 'choice', array('label' => 'Country', 'max_length' => 255, 'required' => false,
            'choices'   => $this->getCountries()))

        ->add('location', 'cities', array('label' => 'Location','required' => false, 'mapped' => true, 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Select Location', 'class'=>'cities') ))
```

Comment: Seriously? We need moooore..... http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: I found solution for this problem now I have entity and form and If need I change structure mu entity. But maybe to be bundle for this task

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information. Are the county fields mapped to a country entity or not?

There are many ways to do this, research more then come back with a method you are trying and code that you have used.

To answer your question,  I would create a form with select lists, hide all but the first then onChange use query to send ajax requests to the backend to fetch data, populate the next select lists then unhide/show them.

Comment: If need country fields mapped to a country entity  I do this. Now I found solution maybe to be bundle for this task